# jquery datepicker on jquery dialog won't show after cancel is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've successfully created a jquery datepicker on jquery's dialog box that was loaded via `load()` function.

I was able to achieve it by overriding dialog box's open event:

```
 open: function (event, ui) {
                    if ($('input.date-picker').length > 0) {
                        $('input.date-picker').datepicker({
                            showOn: "button",
                            buttonImage: "/Content/images/calendar.gif",
                            buttonImageOnly: true
                        });
                        $('input.date-picker').datepicker("refresh");
                    }
                },
```

The datepicker successfully show after I press the image button. But I noticed something strange, when I open the dialog, click cancel then open the dialog again and click the calendar image button, the datepicker won't show.

Might help, I've also overriden dialog's close event:

```
close: function (event, ui) {
                    $('input.date-picker').datepicker("destroy");
                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the close function you try to destroy datepicker on input where class is `date-picker` but after previous call to datepicker creation the class of the input has changed to `hasDatepicker` so try to use

```
$('input.hasDatepicker').datepicker("destroy");
```

Edit :

The datepicker should implement this `close` method :

```
close: function (event, ui) {
     $('input.hasDatepicker').datepicker("destroy");
     $(this).dialog("destroy");
     $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem is firefox cache. It shows now (after clearing the cache), but I got another problem. When I click a date it doesn't populate the textbox :-?. This happen after clicking 'Cancel' from the dialog box. Then reopening the dialog box and select a date.

Comment: Update your code in your question please. Ive not enough informations to give you an answer. I'm not sure I'll be able to help you for this btw. In fact, i've experienced the same problem and the only solution was to use an other JS based calendar...

Comment: The code is still the same I've just changed the css class date-picker to hasDatepicker. I'm currently tracing jquery-ui-1.8.16, I might be able to give more info later.

Comment: To those interested I was able to resolved the problem by adding $(this).remove(); in the dialog's close method. Here's the complete code: http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2012/01/add-jquery-datepicker-on-jquery-dialog.html

Comment: thank you! it works.
In my tests though, 

    $('input.hasDatepicker').datepicker("destroy");
    $(this).dialog("destroy");
are not necessary.

    $(this).remove(); 
is enough but I don't understand why it works.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was  -

Inside the dialog, if I have multiple inputs with class `datepicker` , then

```
$(".datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

Basically, to remove the class `hasDatepicker` before initializing `datepicker` again.

I was on **version 1.8.18** of *jquery.ui.datepicker*